# Remove UIRefreshControl default spinner

Tags: spinner, uiactivityindicatorview, uirefreshcontrol

I have subclassed `UIRefreshControl` to make my own, and I can manage everything except one thing :

The default spinner is always visible, and is of course in the middle of everything I've done in my custom implementation.

I can't find the spinner property or whatever it is I need to put to a clear color, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To hide spinner loader in a `UIRefreshControl`, set the `.tintColor` property to a clear color.

e.g. (Swift):

```
mRefreshControl.tintColor =.clear
```

Comment: It's better to give some explanation of why they should try this code. How does it solve the problem?

Comment: In fact, it wasn't a smart response, i have edited it. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 8):

For 2023, `.tintColor = .clear` works fine.

Historic answer:

---

**Swift 4, Swift 5**

**Bug fix**

From time to time only this code doesn't work properly:

`refreshControl.tintColor = .clear` – first reload shows the indicator :(

This fixes this bug:

```
refreshControl.tintColor = .clear 
refreshControl.subviews.first?.alpha = 0
```

Comment: @user3788747, this is the reason for such answers.

Answer (score 1):

Override `didMoveToSuperview` to hide the spinner's superview.

## Swift version:

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()

    guard let _ = superview else { return }

    self.subviews.first?.alpha = 0 // set hidden = true did not work
}
```

## Objective-C version:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    [super didMoveToSuperview];

    if (self.superview != nil && self.subviews.count > 0) {
        self.subviews[0].alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

You may want to do more checks rather than just using the first subview.